# netty 3.6.0 ssl timeout example

Tags: ssl, netty

For the ssl handshake timeout example, how can you call the ImmediateExecutor.INSTANCE since it is package protected

```
final Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();

final SslBufferPool pool = new SslBufferPool();


final class MyChannelPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {

public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {

ChannelPipeline cp = Channels.pipeline();



SslEngine engine = ...

// Use a handshake timeout of 10 seconds

SslHandler handler = new SslHandler(engine, pool, false, ImmediateExecutor.INSTANCE, timer, 10000);

cp.addFirst("ssl", handler);

return cp;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug.. I will fix it for 3.6.2.Final as the release process for 3.6.1.Final was started already.

In the meanwhile you can just "clone" the class and us it:

```
public final class ImmediateExecutor implements Executor {

    /**
     * The default instance.
     */
    public static final ImmediateExecutor INSTANCE = new ImmediateExecutor();

    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        command.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Was fixed and will be part of 3.6.2.Final